# converting xml into array, undesired array output

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am trying to convert xml into associative array.

```
  foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  $ages[$child->getName()] = $child;
  }
```

But when I print out this array 'ages', I am getting output as

```
[Quagmire] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 30
        )
```

instead of

```
[Quagmire] => 30
```

What change do I make to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly cast the value of the child from a SimpleXML object to an int.

```
    $ages[$child->getName()] = (int)$child;
```

Answer (score -2):

Yeah the problem with SimpleXML Objects is that they are not entirely objects. They are actually resources. Which is why you run into this issue. I ran into this a few years ago when I was trying to serialize an XML object for later use.

What you need to do is write a function that will do the convert. Now normally I would write one out, but it turns out a number of people in the PHP community have already tackled this problem and posted it on the php.net website.

The below code comes from http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#97555

```
<?php
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array())
{
  $arrData = array();

  // if input is object, convert into array
  if (is_object($arrObjData))
    $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);

  if (is_array($arrObjData))
  {
    foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value)
    {
      if (is_object($value) || is_array($value))
        $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call

      if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices))
        continue;

      $arrData[$index] = $value;
    }
  }

  return $arrData;
}
?>

Usage:

<?php
$xmlUrl = "feed.xml"; // XML feed file/URL
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);
print_r($arrXml);
?>
```

The code above was slightly cleaned up by me. I get annoyed by ugly code. Anyway, give that a crack and good luck!

-Patrick

Comment: `Array ( [name] => Quagmire [age] => 30 ) `is not the format that the OP requested. Also `simplexml_load_file` is better than `file_get_contents`, `simplexml_load_string`

Comment: @brian_d I would argue on the point of simplexml_load_file only because using file_get_contents will work better when your getting your XML feeds from Microsoft servers. For some reason those servers tack on some extra stuff that file_get_contents seems to handle well but simplexml_load_file does not. I say this from experience. As for the format, ok so I didn't exactly pay the closest attention to that. I was mainly making the point that looking at the PHP.net documentation can often find this stuff written for you already.